# Swagger2 config class not loaded in spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc, swagger, swagger-2.0

I am working on setting up swagger2 documentation for my Spring REST Project. But when I try to execute http://localhost:8085/swagger-ui.html returns empty page.The problem is my bean class is not loaded by my spring MVC application and it is NOT a spring boot application.

The below is my swagger2 config class

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
@EnableWebMvc
public class SwaggerConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    @Bean
    public Docket newsApi() {
        System.out.println("!@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@22");
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
    .groupName("Dialr")
    .apiInfo(apiInfo())
    .select()
    .paths(regex("/*.*"))
    .build();
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
    return new ApiInfoBuilder()
    .title("Spring REST Sample with Swagger")
    .description("Spring REST Sample with Swagger")
    .termsOfServiceUrl("http://www-03.ibm.com/software/sla/sladb.nsf/sla/bm?Open")
    .contact("Niklas Heidloff")
    .license("Apache License Version 2.0")
    .licenseUrl("https://github.com/IBM-Bluemix/news-aggregator/blob/master/LICENSE")
    .version("2.0")
    .build();
    }

}
```

The below is my rest-servlet.xml under WEB-INF

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
 xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.xx.yy.zz" />

 <mvc:annotation-driven />
<mvc:resources mapping="swagger-ui.html" location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/webjars/**" location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/"/>

<context:annotation-config/>
 <bean name="swaggerConfig" class="com.xx.yy.SwaggerConfig"/>

  </beans>
```

Please find the web.xml entry as well

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Retail_SVC</display-name>


  <servlet>
 <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/rest-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Please let me know if anything is missing ? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Couple of comments: you don't need to `extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`, since you're not doing anything with it. If you're component scanning then you don't need to explicitly declare the `swaggerConfig` bean. Lastly since you're overriding the dispatch servlet you might try hitting `http://localhost:8085/rest/swagger-ui.html`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the base url mapping in your servlet mapping is /rest/* the swagger-ui.html will not load to http://localhost:8085/swagger-ui.html so
try with http://localhost:8085/rest/swagger-ui.html it may work

Comment: you can comment it.

Answer (score 0):

I used the WebMvcConfigurer instead of the WebMvcConfigurerAdapter because that class is already deprecated.

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
  @Bean
  public Docket productApi() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()                
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.illary.controller"))
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build()            
            .apiInfo(metaData());
  }
  private ApiInfo metaData() {
    return new ApiInfoBuilder()
            .title("Spring Boot Swagger App")
            .description("\"Spring Boot Swagger Server App\"")
            .version("1.0.0")
            .license("Apache License Version 2.0")
            .licenseUrl("https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0\"")
            .build();
  }

  public ApiInfo apiInfo() {
    final ApiInfoBuilder builder = new ApiInfoBuilder();
    builder.title("Swagger Test App").version("1.0").license("(C) Copyright Test")
    .description("The API provides a platform to query build test swagger api");

    return builder.build();
  }

  @Override
  public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
    .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");

    registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
    .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
  }
}
```